# Cannot printf a string returned by a function

Tags: c

When i try to print the destination string using printf it shows nothing, i don't understand where the problem is.

```
char   *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    while (*src)
    {
        *dest = *src;
        src++;
        dest++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
    return (dest);
}
void main(void) {
  char s1[25];
  char s2[]="test";
  printf("%s",ft_strcpy(s1, s2));

}
```

dest contains the copied string but the printf prints an empty string

Comment: Voting to close as "simple typographical error"; simply create a copy of `dest` and modify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are changing where the pointer dest points to, your final action is to put 0 at the end of dest, then you return the pointer pointing at this 0 ( a blank string).

either take a copy of dest in the beginning, or don't change dest at all, but introduce a new pointer.  eg,  introducing a copy of dest :-

```
char   *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char* orig_dest = dest;  // this takes a copy of where dest originally pointing to.
    while (*src)
    {
        *dest = *src
        src++;
        dest++;  // this is changing where dest points to...
    }
    *dest = '\0';   // this means dest points at a blank string...
    return (orig_dest);
}
```